# R Compare non side-by-side duplicates in 2 columns

Tags: r, duplicates, compare, unique

There are many similar questions but I'd like to compare 2 columns and delete all the duplicates in both columns so that all that is left is the unique observations in each column. Note: Duplicates are not side-by-side. If possible, I would also like a list of the duplicates (not just TRUE/FALSE). Thanks!

```
        C1 C2
     1  a  z 
     2  c  d
     3  f  a 
     4  e  c
```

would become

```
        C1 C2
     1  f  z
     2  e  d
```

with duplicate list

```
    duplicates: a, c
```

Comment: can you please post an example data frame and the expected result ?

Comment: Added! Thanks ahead of time

Comment: What if the duplicates overlap in rows? For example, one row has an `a` and the other doesn't. Would you delete the entire row?

Comment: No I would just delete the 'a' in one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R method using `duplicated` and `lapply`.

```
temp <- unlist(df)
# get duplicated elements
myDupeVec <- unique(temp[duplicated(temp)])

# get list without duplicates
noDupesList <- lapply(df, function(i) i[!(i %in% myDupeVec)])

noDupesList
$C1
[1] "f" "e"

$C2
[1] "z" "d"
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="   C1 C2
     1  a  z 
     2  c  d
     3  f  a 
     4  e  c ", as.is=TRUE)
```

Note that this returns a list. This is much more flexible structure, as there is generally a possibility that a level may be repeated more than once in a particular variable. If this is not the case, you can use `do.call` and `data.frame` to put the result into a rectangular structure.

```
do.call(data.frame, noDupesList)
  C1 C2
1  f  z
2  e  d
```

Comment: Thank you! Just wondering, is there a way that does this for 10000 rows?

Comment: This will work for 10K or 10M rows. `unlist` puts all this into a long vector. It can become difficult with memory and time etc, but typically with sufficient memory, just a bit of patience. I added `unique` to the second line as that has the potential of speeding up some comparisons.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer

```
 where_dupe <- which(apply(df, 2, duplicated), arr.ind = T)
```

Gives you the location of the duplicated elements within your original data frame.

```
col_unique <- setdiff(1:ncol(df), where_dupe)
```

Gives you which columns had no duplicates

You can find out the values by indexing.

```
df[,col_unique]
```